# Action requires multiple controllers to execute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a UserController that has a Destroy function. It is a rather complex function because it demands to destroy all user's data. I have another action, from the Admin panel that deletes all data from a specific set of users.

Since I don't want to replicate the code from the UserController, I would like to call the Destroy function from UserController for each User to destroy its data.

How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why not move this functionality to a common class method which can be accessed from both the controllers as needed ?

```
public class UserManager
{
  public void Destroy(List<int> userIdsToDestroy)
  {
    foreach(var userId in userIdsToDestroy)
    {
       //Execute code to destroy
    }
  }
}
```

and from your action methods, you can call it like

```
var mgr = new UserManager();
var badUsers  = new List<int> { 1,2,3};
mgr.Destroy(badUsers);
```

Update the `badUsers` variable value as needed based on from where you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Shared functionality like this would ideally be in a business layer, and both controllers would call that code. If it's a little app, you could just create a separate folder structure for shared code. Larger projects would have a business layer dll.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the `Destroy()` method as a `Non-Action` method then like

```
[Non-Action]
public void Destroy(User user)
{
  // code goes here
}
```

You can as well make this `Destroy()` function as part of your business layer logic instead of handling this in controller. In that case, you call it from anywhere.

If you want it to be @controller, you can as well consider usig `[ChildActionOnly]` action filter attribute.